# How would you build a custom report for mobile analytics using existing tools (iphone, ipad, android, etc..)?

Tags: iphone, mobile, report, analytics

Hi we have an app which is free and sponsored by ads. I'd like to create a reporting tool which allows me and the rest of the team to track important statistics for the app such as users, impressions, ads, etc...

We use a number of tools already to track the stats such as Flurry Analytics, the ad servers reports, etc..

Do you have any idea on how I could present all these dynamically? FLurry has an external API to json and xml.

My best option would be an internal web page which presents the data but I'd like to find a tool to build that and not build the web page from scratch..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [Picok](http://www.picok.org/en/) or the [Homebox module](http://drupal.org/project/homebox) for Drupal would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks. I am more looking for a tool where I could plugin an API and produce graphs, etc..  There are a few dashboard solutions out there but either they're way too advanced or they just handle data from a limited set of services like Google analytics, etc..